# npx is not working after installing node 16.3.0 on ubuntu 21.10 with nvm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I installed node js using nvm first I installed version 17.1.0 I had some problems with node-gyp , so I downgraded to 16.3.0 (current lts) .
but every script I am runing using npx causeing me an error

```
spawn <package npx need to run> ENOENT
```

If I am installing the package globaly it will work only in the same terminal session

Answer (score 1):

I understand this may not be the best solution but I have been having problems with nvm and versions not actually switching So I would start by looking at your current node version

`node -v`

And check your npx version with

`npx -v`

Anything above node 5.2 should have npx already installed but on the off chance that it isn't you can install it with

`npm install -g npx`

If this is all installed, theoretically it should all work but I understand you are having issues. This is not an ideal solution, but you could

`npm i <package-name>`

`npm run <package-name>`

Hopefully this at least allows you to continue working while finding out why npx isn't working on your machine.

Another npm version manager alternative is n if you'd like to check them out and see if you have any better luck installing and changing node versions
https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

Comment: I tried to install npx but it didn't solve the problem , I also tried to install the package localy and run it with "npm run" but it was not stable( failed every time there was a "new terminal") I ended up usind node ./node_modules/.... in my package json but for sure this is no long term solution

Comment: If this is still going on, I'd be curious as to what your bash_profile file looks like (or whatever shell you are using). I say this because it fails every time there is a new terminal. I'm no expert in shell but I might look there